# Finder window on top of full-screen safari?

Tags: macos, finder, safari, high-sierra, data-transfer

I wish it were possible to press a keyboard shortcut while in full-screen Safari, have a finder window appear in the middle of the screen, and then drag+drop files from that finder window to safari.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your aware of the split screen function? Click the green window icon pressed  a bit longer. You then put safari on one side and finder on the other, you can change the ratio (default 50/60)

Comment: @Roger the problem is that I browse full-screen safari probably upwards of ten hours a day. In the rare cases that I need to upload a file, I'd just like finder to pop-up, and then I can drag'n'drop. Rearranging my entire screen space for a ten second operation is overkill.

Comment: I read you! :-) I'm also not always happy how it works. I don't know how much screen real estate you have,if I split screen and then drag the middle completely to the side, i'm guessing i have 80-85% of Safari. Not a great solution, but maybe something that could work.

Answer (score 3):

Rather clunky, but possible...

- Go back to Finder, select & grab your files; keep hold of them.
- either...

  - Use your Show Dashboard key command & hover your cursor [still holding the files] over the Safari Space until it pops to the front, or
  - Use  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>num</kbd>  to go to the last Space before your fullscreen app, then  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd>  to get to fullscreen.
- Drop the files.

This is always going to be hindered by fullscreen apps being to the right of any & all numbered Spaces.

You may need to enable the Ctrl/key functionality first in System Prefs/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Mission Control

[image]

Only alternative I can think of is use the Open dialog, or as suggested elsewhere, don't fullscreen, just maximise.

Comment: Well, atm I'd just go to finder, then drag the files to the side of the screen (which switches spaces) and then drop into Safari.

Comment: I guess if you don't use Spaces, or have finder on the rightmost space, that works too. I have 2 screens & 7 spaces... which makes it more of a challenge, as Finder is on Space 1 & anything fullscreen is on >7. Another reason I never actually use fullscreen ;)

Comment: I'm usually just two spaces, safari is space 1 (full screened) and then a desktop on the second (rightmost unless playing fullscreen video from safari, which is common) and in that desktop my other apps are open (terminal, mail, discord, finder most commonly)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no applications can run on top of a full-screen application. Not even stickies, which work well on top of other applications. If you want a similar full screen effect while using finder on top you can use these 2 methods:

- Click on Window on the top status bar than click on Zoom to widen the viewing angles.
- Place your mouse arrow near the corners or edges of the Safari window and then stretch Safari all of the way to each section of the Mac display.

Either method will allow you to view the website and still keep the Safari screen large while multitasking via another application.

Comment: holding alt and then clicking the green top-left button maximises the window instead of entering full screen

Comment: Yes you can use that shortcut as well.

Comment: Hm, I thought TotalFinder's visor was a counterexample to your "no applications can run on top of a full-screen application" claim, but I just tested it and it does indeed seem to not open properly on top of full-screened safari. Maybe it worked on past versions of macOS

Comment: DefaultFolderX can also open on top of fullscreen - but of course that's only for file-picker dialogs, which idk is truly relevant to this - though it does have a nice click-through feature so you can click directly into any open finder window no matter what's in the way visually.